# How to layer 2 svg images

Tags: javascript, css, svg, mask, clip

I would apreciate if you can guide me in the right direction.

I require to layer two **svg** images using **JS** or **CSS** like the example Image i have below (Phone and a Graphic) so it appears to be as one image.

Thank you

[image: iPhone]

Comment: Yes, I know that and I've already searched for possible solutions. As I know, we can't use `image` as mask in svg, so I ask people not to code the solution, but help me to find any idea how to solve that.

Answer (score 2):

I create this plunkr for your question:
https://plnkr.co/edit/RPAA1JkRM6Or1pY9yMeI

```css
.container-iphone {
    width: 657px;
    height: 588px;
}
.container-iphone img {
 position: absolute;
 z-index: 2;
}
.container-iphone .inside {
  padding-top: 50px;
 text-align: center;
  transform: translate(50%,50%);
  position: relative;
  width: 339px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>

<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Iphone Mask - Jonathan Muszkat</title>
  <meta name="description" content="Iphone Mask">
  <meta name="author" content="Jonathan Muszkat">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">
</head>

<body>
 <div class="container-iphone">
  <img src="http://i.imgur.com/WXt6Pyu.png" />
  <div class="inside">whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever<br/> whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever whatever <div>
 </div>
</body>
</html>
```

as you can see I modify your iphone image and create a div inside so in that div you could put whatever you want. also SVG.

Thanks,
Jonathan

[result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xw5NR.png)

Comment: Yeah, but I have to say I have _a lot_ of such images, about 1000 photos.

Comment: Thats not a problem. you could replicate this. also with a script to have 1000.